# Articles on Care of terminally ill patients according to Halacha

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, choleh-sick

Can someone suggest a well-written article on the treatment of terminally ill patients according to Halacha?

Comment: See this *teshuva* from Igros Moshe https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=312

Comment: Thank you, will read, but can you find anything in English?

Answer (score 4):

There is plenty of material available online, e.g.,

- this summary on [Jewish Perspectives on End-of-Life Care](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/jewish-perspectives-on-end-of-life-care/) from MyJewishLearning
- [Treatment of Terminally Ill Patients According to Jewish Law](https://journalofethics.ama-assn.org/article/treatment-terminally-ill-patients-according-jewish-law/2013-12) by Dov Linzer in AMA Journal of Ethics
- [The Terminally Ill Patient](https://www.medethics.org.il/articles/rc041060a/) from Prof. Avraham Steinberg of Shaare Zedek hospital
- [The Critical Role of Religion: Caring for the Dying Patient from an Orthodox Jewish Perspective](http://bikurcholim.net/static/pdf/the_critical_role_of_religion,_caring_for_the_dying_patient_from_an_orthodox_jewish_perspective.pdf) by many authors incl. R Willig and R Tendler
- a translation of [all relevant responsa of R Moshe Feinstein](https://www.sefaria.org/Care_of_the_Critically_Ill?lang=bi) from the book Care of the Critically Ill authored by R Moshe David Tendler, the son-in-law of R Moshe
- Caring for the Terminally Ill: [Halachic Approaches to Withholding and Withdrawing of Therapy](https://www.medethics.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/RJ051022a.html) by Joshua Kunin
- [Is There Patient Autonomy in Halacha?](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/PatientAutonomy.pdf) by R Zev Schostak

Comment: Thank you, mbloch!